# I'm trying to add empty hair curves to the entire mesh but it's only being applied to a small row of edges, any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Tags: modeling, mesh, particles, hair, 3d-printing

This is going to be 3d printed, so I do need the particles to have volume.

[image]

I created a mesh based on the topology of a head I'm working on in order to have a separate object with hair curves. However after going into sculpt mode, I'm trying to create different density across the entire model, but the density is only being applied to a specific region on the mesh. Any ideas what I could be doing wrong?

I do not encounter the same issue when doing a hair particles systems, however I cannot edit [comb] the particles after I have converted them into a mesh, which is the only way to give the particles any kind of volume.

Comment: never mind, solved it